# Unicode works in .py script, but not in frozen .exe [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, freeze

So, I'm writing this code that sends data to the server, to be displayed to the user. I'm having trouble with the unicode characters. When I run the script from my IDE, the server gets the "correct", unicode str, and it is displayed properly, but upon freezing the script using py2exe or cx_Freeze, and running the .exe file, the display is consisted of ??? ??? ??? instead of characters.

I'm assuming this is due to the encoding used to freeze the script? I have very little experience with encoding, so please forgive me my ignorance. Here is the code in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  #someone suggested this would solve the problem

import os, time, json, urllib2, getpass, socket, subprocess, ast, ctypes, sys

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8') # another suggestion was to force UTF-8 to be def encoding
subprocess.Popen('chcp 65001', shell=True) # thought I'd give it a go forcing cmd to use utf-8

EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW

def get_active_window(): #function that gives me the title of the active window (unicode)
    hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
    buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
    return buff.value

def send_server(data, url): #sending data to the server
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    return urllib2.urlopen(req, data).read()

send_server(get_active_window(), "http://foo.com");
```

Just a reminder, this works when ran from the IDE, so I'm guessing the problem occurs when I'm freezing the script?

Thanks for any help in advance!!!!

EDIT: I've fixed the encoding to match coding: name, still no luck

Comment: Quick note, type(get_active_window()) returns <unicode>

Comment: Your IDE does not use the (shitty) windows commandline window for output, that's why it works. To use Codepage 65001, you have to use special fonts for the command window. Always test your scripts from commandline first.

Answer (score 1):

I had a pretty similar script here that does the same thing and I've used CxFreeze to distribute my app, but it's slightly different from yours. Also I've used Python2.7 and have tested on Windows XP, 7, 8 and 10.

But before trying mine solution, I've realized that your encoding line is wrong, because it need to be like this [according to docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html):

> coding: name or coding=name in the comment.

So, you have to **put : or =**

If you want, you can try this way that works for me:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow 
active_window = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
```

I've used [this great website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) to download win32gui

Comment: I figured out that the encoding line is wrong, I've fixed it. Still nothing :/
I've been using win32gui, but it doesn't solve my problem, so I switched to ctypes. When the window title is in unicode, win32gui gives mi str by default, and decoding after it read '????' does nothing :/

Comment: You need to know what kind of decode it's using...the usual ones are utf-8, ascii and latin-1... ascii is the default when using "".decode(), but try with the other 2 and see if it works @BulseEye